# BigQuery GROUP BY/GROUP EACH BY resources exceeded error, but the query doesn't contain a GROUP BY operator

Tags: google-bigquery

This query:

```
SELECT spin_id, COUNT(*) over(partition by spin_id) notes, note
FROM
 (
   SELECT spin_id, idfa, note, amount, balance, machine
   FROM islot.ledger2, islothd.ledger2
   WHERE machine =‘SlotMachineG2.SlotMachine41’ AND ds >= ‘2014-11-20’
 ) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH views.internal_devices b
ON a.idfa = b.ios_idfa
WHERE b.ios_idfa is null
ORDER BY notes ASC;
```

... reliably fails with:

> Resources exceeded during query execution. The query contained a GROUP
>   BY operator, consider using GROUP EACH BY instead.

... but this query, somewhat obviously, doesn't contain a GROUP BY. Normally we'd just promote any JOIN/GROUP clauses to their equivalent EACH, but it's not clear to me where to apply this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of output are you expecting?  Does the query give you the proper results when you limit this to very small outputs (such as by limiting the sub-select's where-clause to a tiny number of rows)?

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if one of the tables you are querying over is a [Table View](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#views) that itself is defined as a "GROUP BY" query. Given that the table you are joining to is in a dataset called "views", I suspect this is the case.

Comment: Nope, the views are all using GROUP EACH.

Answer (score 0):

Count () Over() is a group by operation. I would try to break down thequery to sub queries, and do the aggregation on lower level.